# Bottleneck when constructing a fairly small numpy array. Indexing issues?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, matrix

Im am currently writing a method for the construction of a specific type of matrix of dimension 12 x 10.

Given a set of barycentric coordinates `B = np.array([b1, b2, b3])` it makes the relevant computations and assembles the matrix using slices. However, while these matrices are quite small, the construction of such a matrix turns out to bottleneck my performance, as I need to construct a few hundred thousand.

### Code

```
import numpy as np
def r1(B):
    """
    :param B: barycentric coordinates np.array([b1, b2, b3]) of point of evaluation
    :return: (12x10) linear evaluation matrix.
    """

    R = np.zeros((12, 10))
    b = np.zeros((3, 3))  # beta
    g = np.zeros(3)  # gamma

    for i in range(3):
        g[i] = 2 * B[i] - 1
        for j in range(3):
            b[i, j] = B[i] - B[j]

    R[[0, 1], 0] = g[0]
    R[[2, 3], 1] = g[1]
    R[[4, 5], 2] = g[2]

    R[[1, 2, 7, 8], 3] = [2 * b[1, 2], 2 * b[0, 2], 2 * b[1, 2], 2 * b[0, 2]]
    R[[3, 4, 9, 10], 4] = [2 * b[2, 0], 2 * b[1, 0], 2 * b[2, 0], 2 * b[1, 0]]
    R[[0, 5, 6, 11], 5] = [2 * b[2, 1], 2 * b[0, 1], 2 * b[2, 1], 2 * b[0, 1]]
    R[[0, 1, 6, 7], 6] = [4 * B[1], 4 * B[2], 4 * b[0, 2], 4 * b[0, 1]]
    R[[2, 3, 8, 9], 7] = [4 * B[2], 4 * B[0], 4 * b[1, 0], 4 * b[1, 2]]
    R[[4, 5, 10, 11], 8] = [4 * B[0], 4 * B[1], 4 * b[2, 1], 4 * b[2, 0]]
    R[6:, 9] = -3 * np.array([g[0], g[0], g[1], g[1], g[2], g[2]])

    return R
```

Is there any way of speeding up this? I am not familiar with numpy broadcasting, but I've heard the buzzword.

### Example run:

```
b = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.4])
r1(b)
```

### cProfile results for 125751 calls to `r1`:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
125751    6.784    0.000    7.244    0.000 helper_functions.py:262(r1)
377253    0.267    0.000    0.267    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.zeros}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
125751    0.193    0.000    0.193    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.array}
```

I am not sure how to interpret this cProfile information. Is it the array-allocation that takes time?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: It takes `%timeit r1(b)` --> `34.6 µs ± 726 ns per loop` 34µs to build the matrix. Is that really your bottleneck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few quick optimizations:

```
b = B[:, None] - B[None, :]  # broadcasting
g = 2 * B - 1                # Linear operation

R[0:2, 0] = g[0]             # Slices vs fancy indexing
R[2:4, 1] = g[1]
R[4:6, 2] = g[2]
```

Take down the time from `34 µs` to `27 µs`. Not a huge speedup but it is a start and is more numpy-like. The rest of the code seems fine (without having a in-depth understanding of what the matrix is supposed to be) and it would take a bit more time to further optimize it.

If the speed is really critical for you with this matrix, and the `27 µs` is really your bottleneck, you could probably initialize this matrix quicker from Cython.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the tips! I've changed all the fancy indexing to explicit declaration, which helped a lot, and the broadcasting of `b` is clever.
I had an idea: At the moment, `r1` takes an array of shape `(1,3)` and returns an array of shape `(12, 10)`. Would it be possible to instead take an array of shape `(N, 1, 3)` and return an array of shape `(N, 12, 10)` using broadcasting, and would this give any speed-ups?

Comment: @IvarStangeby yes it should be totally fine. You would just have to add extra slicing to every slicing operation: e.g. `b = B[:, :, None] - B[:, None, :]`.